# Плоская модель памяти

Tags: память, виртуальная-память, сегментация

[Источник](https://star-wiki.ru/wiki/Flat_memory_model#Paged_memory_model) говорит, что `модель плоской памяти - парадигма, в которой память представляется программе как единое непрерывное адресное пространство. ЦП может напрямую (и линейно) адресовать все доступные без необходимости прибегать к каким-либо видам схемы сегментации памяти или подкачки`. Слышал, что такая модель памяти сейчас используется везде, но каким образом тогда память программы все равно разбивается на сегменты кода, данных и т. д., а так же на страницы? Если программы сегментированы, не означает ли это что я использую  [сегментированную модель](https://star-wiki.ru/wiki/Flat_memory_model#Paged_memory_model) памяти?
А так же каким образом плоская модель памяти относится к виртуальной памяти, это не то же самое? Или например одно является реализацией другого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В плоской модели памяти "Flat" можно забыть о сегментных регистрах, и о сегментах в целом - это пережиток прошлого. Связано это с тем, что в дескрипторах (которые описывают сегменты) всегда выставляется макс.возможный размер этих сегментов, и начальный адрес нуль. Причём это действительно для всех сегм.регистров, типа `CS\DS\SS\ES\FS\GS`. Если система 32-битная, то размер (лимит) сегмента в дескрипторах имеет значение `0хFFFFFFFF` (4Gb), а база = `0`. Данный лимит совпадает с размером регистров 32-битного процессора, поэтому в вашем источнике утверждается, что:

> ЦП может напрямую (и линейно) адресовать все доступное пространство,
> без необходимости прибегать к каким-либо видам схемы сегментации
> памяти или подкачки.

Если открыть отладчик **"OllyDbg"**, то в окне-регистров ЦП можно обнаружить значение всех сегментных регистров, включая их селекторы (видимую часть), и базу с лимитом в дескрипторах. Здесь видно, что у всех кроме `FS` база нуль, и лимит макс. В данном случае регистр(FS) имеет базу `0x7FFDF000` и лимит `0x0FFF` - система выделяет этот сегмент (размером в одну 4К-страницу) под инфо\структуру **ТЕВ** процесса, Thread Environment Block. При этом в дескрипторе сегмента(FS) выставляется атрибут(R) "только чтение". 2-мл.бита во-всех селекторах имеют значение(3), что говорит о пользовательском приложении третьего кольца (биты RPL).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Виртуальная память подразумевает разбиение огромных сегментов размером в 4Gb, на более мелкие страницы по 4Кb. Например, если у приложения всего одна строчка текста, то зачем выделять под неё все 4Gb памяти, оформив их как сегмент-данных? Поэтому ввели страницы, которые (при нехватке физ.памяти) в любой момент можно выгрузить на диск в файл-подкачки, и выделить освободившееся место под новые данные. По сути, программу любого размера можно отобразить всего в одной вирт.странице памяти - как отработает один 4К-блок, выгружаем и заменяем его новой порцией инфы. Только работать такая программа будет медленно.

Атрибуты страницам назначаются в записях **РТЕ**, и они имеют приоритет перед атрибутами в дескрипторах сегментных регистров. Именно поэтому говорят, что *при страничной организации, в плоской модели памяти можно вообще принебречь сегментами*. К примеру вот код, который специально обращается к секции-данных, через сегментный регистр кода `CS:offset`, хотя по идее должна быть пара `DS:offset`. Точно так-же внутри кода можно осуществлять переходы через `DS`. Это ещё раз подтверждает, что сегментные регистры в РМ не играют никакой роли - они передали все свои полномочия вирт.страницам.

```
format   pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry    start
;//---------- 
.data
jump   dd   @prn      ;//<--- переменная в секции-данных, с адресом перехода
buff   db   0
;//----------
.code
start:   mov     ecx,-1
         mov     ebx,'DEAD'
         nop
         mov     eax,[cs:jump]   ;// Внимание! Указываю секцию-кода + значение из секции-данных!
         jmp     eax

        cinvoke  printf,<' Hello World!',0>   ;//<-- блок не получит управления
         jmp     @exit

@prn:   cinvoke  printf,<' Jump OK!',0>       

@exit:  cinvoke  _getch     ;// клавиша
        cinvoke  exit,0     ;// выход!
;//----------
section '.idata' import data readable
library   msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
include  'api\msvcrt.inc'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> А так же каким образом плоская модель памяти относится к виртуальной
> памяти, это не то же самое? Или например одно является реализацией
> другого?

Плоская Flat - это модель памяти от нуля и до макс. с аналогичными по размеру регистрами ЦП, что позволяет адресовать всю память одним регистром. А вирт.память - это технология (алгоритм) распределения физ.памяти ОЗУ, путём замещения одних физ.страниц, другими.

В системе имеется база-данных **PFN** (PageFrameNumber), а у каждого процесса свое древо **VAD** (Virtual Address Descriptor) и набор рабочих страниц **"WorkingSet"**. При вытеснении ненужных страниц в файл-подкачки, благодаря VAD и PFN система ведёт учёт, какому именно процессу они принадлежат, чтобы при необходимости вернуть их опять в память именно своего, а не чужого процесса (вирт.адреса у всех процессов одинаковы).

Answer (score 4):

Используются одни и те же слова для объяснения разных феноменов.

Шестнадцатибитный процессор может одним своим регистром адресовать 64 кило памяти. 64 кило - один сегмент. Чтобы адресовать побольше памяти, нужно использовать два регистра - один для сегмента, другой - для смещения в этом сегменте.

А еще были такие [карты расширения памяти, с которыми можно было общаться через форточку в 64 килобайта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C), и [переключение банков в машинах Commodore](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Bank_Switching).

Все вышеперечисленное - это сегментная организация памяти.

Тот факт, что авторы формата ELF и EXE придумали называть куски памяти, куда они засовывают константы, код программы и кучу тоже словом *сегмент* связывает одно с другим только исторически - потому что в староглиняные времена пара регистров SS:SP указывала на стек и называлась "сегмент стека", а регистр CS, например, указывал на сегмент кода (который .code).

Сейчас пару регистров (и сегментную адресацию) никто не использует, но деление памяти на сегменты осталось, а термины тянуться еще с тех времен.